# Autocomplete through form

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I was going to build autocomplete using remix.run, but then it occurred to me that would be relying too much on routing and forms to select/focus the input after each submit, this can not produce good UX. The user will input something into form, the form gets submitted, he awaits response, and then the input is focused again, and the ux here that this is instantsearch/autocomplete.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, however most autocompletes work with user input via a technique called "debouncing". User input change events are captured, and only after a short time of inactivity (eg 100ms) is the search request sent, this way less requests occur, and UI is snappier. If a request is in flight and a user continues typing the previous request can be cancelled and the new more specific search term would be sent instead next time they pause, guaranteeing no race conditions and that the results reflect the correct search term

Comment: the backend load is small, so I don't care for debouncing, and debouncing was meant for slow phones on front end. If remix.run can't support this use case, than I'd rather start making direct fetch calls without it. As far as requests go, I don't know that you can cancel whatever request http form makes, but that would just produce more complexity around making sure that input remains focused within the form that has submitted.

Comment: Hi, can someone have a look at this Remix question? TIA. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300943/onclick-event-listeners-are-not-working-in-remix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is the `useFetcher` hook Remix exports. This hook let you fetch data from the loader of any route without causing a navigation, it was added for this kind of UIs.

```
import { Form, useFetcher } from "remix"

export default function Screen() {
  let fetcher = useFetcher()

  function handleChange(event) {
    let value = event.currentTarget.value
    // load data from a route with a loader
    fetcher.load(`/api/autocomplete?query=${value}`)
  }

  return (
    <Form>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} list="suggestions" />
      <datalist id="suggestions">
        {fetcher.data.map(item => {
          return <option key={item.id} value={item.value} />
        })}
      </datalist>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Something like that, and in the endpoint you load with the fetcher you export a loader

```js
export async function loader({ request }) {
  let url = new URL(request.url)
  let query = url.searchParams.get("query") ?? "";
  let data = await getData(query)
  return json(data)
}
```

Comment: This keeps refreshing my page and I never get the data back :( what could I be missing?